# How can I make commands in Discord.py not allow any extra characters after the actual command?

Tags: python

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong! {0}ms".format(round(bot.latency * 1000)))
```

This is my ping command for my bot I made, however the issue is when I use this command
`-ping`, it works just fine but if I do, `-ping whateverhere`

Then the command still runs! I'm not quite sure why this happens but it accepts the other arguments for some reason. The same happens with my other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the best solution, but what you can actually try is adding an additional argument *arg* (or whatever you'd like to call it) to your function, and set its default value to *None*. Then, in the function's body, you'll want to check if any extra arguments were provided - if not, then the function should just run, if yes - it could throw an exception for you, or send a message to the text channel, where the command was used. See the modified code below:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, arg=None):
    if arg:
        await ctx.send('This command takes no arguments.')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Pong! {0}ms".format(round(bot.latency * 1000)))
```